# importing txt files into python

Tags: python

```
a01:01-24-2011:s1 
a03:01-24-2011:s2 
a02:01-24-2011:s2 
a03:02-02-2011:s2 
a03:03-02-2011:s1 
a02:04-19-2011:s2 
a01:05-14-2011:s2 
a02:06-11-2011:s2 
a03:07-12-2011:s1 
a01:08-19-2011:s1 
a03:09-19-2011:s1 
a03:10-19-2011:s2 
a03:11-19-2011:s1 
a03:12-19-2011:s2
```

this is saved in animallog1.txt. How would I import this file so that it can be used to write code, or answer questions using the above data.
 I have tried:

```
 open('C:/animallog1.txt', 'r')
```

but it does not work and states 
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/animallog1.txt'`
Could someone please help me fix this

Comment: @wwii You need raw string for the backslash `'\'` (or to escape it with another backslash `'\\'`) but not forward slash `'/'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
open('C:\\animallog1.txt', 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Does file animallog1.txt exists?
2. On Windows you should be care for the backsplash.

   ```
   file = open('c:\\path\\to\\file', 'r')
   ```

   or

   ```
   file = open(r'c:\path\to\file', 'r')
   ```
3. Check your workspace, u can use `os.chdir()` to change your directory to `c:\`?

Comment: builtins.ImportError: No module named 'animallog1'

Comment: @user2994135  How could it be? this means u import a non-existent module, and your operation is open a file. I think u used `import animallog1`.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're using Windows, you have to use backslashes. There are a couple ways to do that: one is with double backslashes as others have pointed out, another is using the various constants and functions in the `os` and `os.path` libraries:

```
import os
filename = "C:" + os.sep + "animallog1.txt"
```

Second, the "proper" way to do this is with a `with` statement:

```
with open(filename) as f: #'r' is default
    for line in f:
        a, date, s = line.split(":")
        # ...
```

What the `with` statement does is guarantee that the file gets closed on leaving the `with` block. Otherwise the file doesn't get closed until the Python garbage collector gets around to it.

Comment: the file is saved is Computer-Windows(C:)-User-#my name-documents       if that helps in anyway

Comment: Are you running the Python script in the same place as the file?